# Android Button with bottom margin and state_pressed

Tags: android, xml

Is there a way to create Android `Button` that have bottom margin when `state_pressed` is `false`, and that have rounded corners without bottom margin when `state_pressed` is `true`?

I have this, but it's without bottom margin when `state_pressed` is `false`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape 
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#B5B5B5" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

EDIT: Added pictures

`android:state_pressed="false"`

[image]

`android:state_pressed="true"`

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate with an illustration so that it can be understandable

Comment: @SaiJayant I added pictures.

Comment: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_for_pressed_state" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_for_normal_state" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>

Comment: And then add individual drawable items for your kind of required button drawable

Comment: @SaiJayant thank you, it works! You can answer that if you want so that I can mark it as a best answer.

Comment: You are Welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<selector xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_for_pressed_state" android:state_pressed="true"/> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_for_normal_state" android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

Add this code your drawable folder and use separate button drawables for the different button state

Comment: Tnx 

user3566569